# CanCan Double Nested Resource Permission Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have some problems defining the permissions for a twice nested resource. I have users > companies > orders...

My users have many companies through agreements.

Each company has many orders and each order belongs to a company.

My abilities.rb file contains the following:

```
elsif user.role? :customer_admin
      can [:read, :update], User, :id => user.id
      can [:read, :update], Company, :id => user.id 
      can :read, Company, :users => { :id => user.id }
      can :read, Order, :user => { :id => user.id }
 end
```

And in my orders controller, I have this:

```
 load_and_authorize_resource :company
  load_and_authorize_resource :order, :through => :company
```

The problem is that I can't seem to view the order as the customer_admin

Hope you can help, thanks again.

---- edit ----

user.rb

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_many :agreements
  has_many :companies, :through => :agreements
```

company.rb

```
  has_many :agreements
  has_many :users, :through => :agreements
  has_many :orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

order.rb

```
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :requirements
  has_many :services, :through => :requirements
  has_many :servicelevelagreements
  has_many :slas, :through => :servicelevelagreements
```

agreement.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
```

Hope that's a little more helpful!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `user_id` in orders, which defines the admin user?
It seems that you want to use it in a `has_many :through` association. If that's the case then I suggest to try accessing by defining like this:

```
can :read, Order, :company => { :user_id => user.id }
```

Since `cancan` supports nested associations.

**Update**

My setup assumes that your models looks like:

```
#order.rb

belongs_to :company

#company.rb

belongs_to :user
has_many :orders
```

And your company should contain a field called `user_id` which is the id of the assigned user.

For more information please see the wiki. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources

**Update 2**

The problem is that your your `company` `has_many :users, :through=>:agreements`

This involves the following definition:

```
can :read, Order, :company => { :users => { :id => user.id } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. No, there's no user_id for orders as it's nested in company controller. When I try this, I end up with a not authorised error :( Are my load_and_authorize_resource bits correct? Jx

Comment: @Jenny Blunt , yes your `load_and_authorize` part looks ok. I think that you have problems with role declaration part. I can give you more specific answer if you can provide the relations defined in your models in question. Updated my answer please check it out.